# install SQL server express 2008 r2 on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: sql

I need to install a new invoice software on my pc. It is a Windows' based product and I am trying to run it by wine.

The installation process terminates because of this error: "SQL server express 2008 r2 problem 536870913".

Any ideas? I tried these steps but with no success: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `wine` because the instructions from Microsoft provide details for installing using Linux without it. Also, the [Wine HQ entry](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=22609) for that app rates it as "Garbage", meaning it uses features not yet supported by `wine`.

Instead follow the [instructions for adding their Ubutun repository](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-2017) and installing the software:

```
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017.list)"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server
```

However, be aware this is installing the *2017* version of Microsoft SQL Server, not the 2008 version, if that matters. If for some reason you need that specific (old) version of SQL Server you'll need to install VirtualBox and run Windows within it.